# Is there a lightweight datagrid alternative in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, datagrid

What is the most performant way of displaying a table of data in Flex?

Are there alternatives to the native Flex Datagrid Component? Alternatives that are noted for their rendering speed?

Are there other ways to display a table?

I have a datagrid with roughly 70 lines and 7 columns of simple text data. This is currently created and loaded in memory. This is being refreshed rapidly (about 800 msec) and there is a slight lag in other animations when it is rendering the table... So I am trying to cut down this render time.

Comment: DataGrid is pretty lightweight - it should not take very long to render. You should a profile on your application to see if memory is being eaten up by some other process.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you've got the DataGrid, AdvancedDataGrid, and TileList. But I've never had any speed issues with any of them as such. However, they can become slow based on what you choose to display within the cells, especially if you want to use fat images (in which case your option is to create copies at a lower resolution).

All the controls are pretty good at loading and displaying content only as it is required based on scrolling into view.

How slow is your problem case? What (and how much) are you putting into the cells? Do you know for sure it's Flex, or could it be in your data provider?

Answer (score 1):

Do you need a datagrid? If you don't need resizable columns, you could also use a List and a custom itemrenderer. Say you have 10 rows and 4 columns. A datagrid would create 40 items vs a List which would create 10.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ElfGrid here: http://www.elfgrid.com/

Answer (score -2):

You can use the <mx:Grid> component. Its slightly lighter than datagrid.

Comment: grid and datagrid are completely different things

Comment: mx:Grid is too low to display >_<